# Setup Asymptote in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, windows, asymptote

[Here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Asymptote%3a_Advanced_Configuration) it says that to setup Asymptote in TeXnicCenter, one should put

```
-batchView -tex "pdflatex" %tc-*.asy
```

into the Arguments line.

But there is no Arguments line in Texmaker. Instead, there is only one line corresponding to Asymptote in "Configure Texmaker". Entering

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Asymptote/asy.exe"  -batchView -tex "pdflatex" %tc-*.asy
```

leads to

> error: could not load module 'C:/Users/Dominik/Documents/Latex/test5tc-*.asy

I suspect the reason is that in Texmaker the symbol `%` actually stands for the filename.

By the way, using

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Asymptote/asy.exe" %.asy
```

on a simple code

```
draw((0,0)--(100,100));
draw((0,100)--(100,0));
dot((50,50));`
```

does give the result in GSView. But I want to use Asymptote in my LaTeX files and also output it in PDF, so I need to configure that somehow.

Answer (score 5):

All is automatic with Texmaker :

1. For the asymptote command in Texmaker, just use

   ```
   "C:/Program Files (x86)/Asymptote/asy.exe" %.asy
   ```
2. If you use inline asymptote figure (code into `.tex` document), just use the

   > PdfLaTex + Asymptote + PdfLatex + View Pdf

   mode for the "quick build" command and hit <kbd>F1</kbd> : all the figures will be automatically compiled.
3. If you edit asymptote figures `.asy` directly, Texmaker (>=4.0) will switch automatically in a special "quick build" mode for asymptote: just hit <kbd>F1</kbd> and the pdf of the figure will be displayed automatically after compilation.

See the [Texmaker user manual](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION44).

Comment: I should have written that that doesn't work. PdfLatexing a .tex file with the use of the asymptote package for some reason leads to the fatal error "LaTeX Error: File 'asymptote.asy' not found". But I do have Asymptote installed.

Comment: Can someone please help? I really need Asymptote for my project.

Comment: @DominikTeiml Just to know, did you install Asymptote separately or are you using the one which comes with TeX Live?

Comment: Your problem is not related to Texmaker but with your asymptote installation. If you use miktex, you must copy the "asycolors.sty" and "asymptote.sty" files (from "C:\Program Files(x86)\Asymptote" ) to the "C:\Program Files(x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex" folder. Then, you have to launch the "Miktex settings" program and click on the "Refresh FNDB" button in the "general" tab.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my comment. I mean copy the files to the "C:\Program Files(x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\asymptote" (you have to create the "asymptote" subfolder before copying the files)

Comment: Thanks, I think I am getting closer:
When I quick build a Latex file with Asymptote code (using pdflatex + asymptote + pdflatex + view pdf), I get a pdf with all the latex except for the asymptote diagram. Instead, I get an error: "Cannot execute C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.71\bin\gswin32c.exe Please put in a file config.asy: import settings; gs="LOCATION"; where LOCATION specifies the location of Ghostscript". This is because this gs x32 folder is actually empty. But I don't want to use gs x32. What should I change? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79183060/Other%20work/texmaker.PNG

Comment: By the way, the erorr is longer than this, these are the first two sentences.

Comment: Ok, so I added `-gs="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.07/bin/gswin64.exe"` to my Asymptote command and that seemed to do the trick! Now everything works except for the labels, for which I am getting a similar error as just now for Ghostscript. I posted a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117865/configuring-pdflatex-for-labels-in-asymptote.