# Configuring pdflatex for labels in Asymptote

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, asymptote

Asymptote now works just fine except for when I try to add labels (that are created using LaTeX). In that case, I get

> Process started
>
> Cannot execute C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe/pdflatex
>   Please put in a file config.asy: import settings; texpath="LOCATION";
>   where LOCATION specifies the location of the directory containing your
>   pdflatex engine (pdflatex). Alternatively, set the environment
>   variable ASYMPTOTE_TEXPATH or use the command line option
>   -texpath="LOCATION". For further details, see http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Configuring.html
>   http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Search-paths.html
>
> Process exited with error(s)

My Asymptote command in Texmaker is set to

> "C:/Program Files (x86)/Asymptote/asy.exe" -gs="C:/Program
>   Files/gs/gs9.07/bin/gswin64.exe" -texpath="C:\MiKTeX
>   2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" %.asy

(Nothing works without specifying the ghostscript location.) But I am also specifically stating the pdflatex location as the error says I should do, and I am still getting the error. What should I do? (Btw, yes, all the paths are correct, my pdflatex.exe really is at that location.)

Comment: I think you're setting a wrong `texpath`. It should be a path so something like `-texpath="C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\"` would do

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

You can put most of the stuff in a configuration file `config.asy`. The position of the file is in your user DOS directory `%USERPROFILE%\.asy`. Run the following in a command window to obtain the directory:

```
>echo %USERPROFILE%\.asy
```

Create a new or change the existing file `config.asy` (my own setup)

```
import settings;
gs        = "C:\usr\gs\gs9.06\bin\gswin64c.exe";
psviewer  = "C:\usr\gs\Ghostgum\gsview\gsview64.exe";
pdfviewer = "C:\usr\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe";
```

If TeX is not in your standard search path, you can add

```
texpath   = "C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\";
```

Then you can run: `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Asymptote/asy.exe" -V -f pdf %.asy`

Comment: Where should I put the config.asy file in Linux?

Comment: @qed Look in the Asymptote documentation

Answer (score 7):

There is a mistake in your command line. In fact, `-texpath` should point to a path and not to an executable. In other words, it should point to a directory (a folder) rather than a file.

So changing your command line to

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Asymptote/asy.exe" -gs="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.07/bin/gswin64.exe" -texpath="C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\" %.asy
```

it's the trick to get it working.