# Running Asymptote in one go

Tags: asymptote

I've followed the tutorial on [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Asymptote:_Advanced_Configuration) to implementing and using Asymptote in LaTeX.

However I don't want to go through the 3 steps that they outlined (build output > run asymptote > build and run) every time I want to view my LaTeX file. I want to be able to just hit "Build and Run" and view my LaTeX files with Asymptote pictures in them.

They mentioned that there is a solution to this that uses batch files, but I have no experience with them. Can someone show me how to do this?

Edit: I'm using TeXnicCenter with MikTeX

Comment: You'll need to specify your IDE. If, for example, you are using TeXmaker then [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117287/setup-asymptote-in-texmaker) is how it can be set up.

Comment: One approach is to use the [asypictureB](https://ctan.org/pkg/asypictureb?lang=en) package with shell-escape. Another alternative is to use [latexmk](https://ctan.org/pkg/asypictureb?lang=en).

Comment: I have neither Windows nor Texniccenter but isn't the third method from your linked page which is "...only applicable when you have Asymptote code inside the Asymptote Environment in LaTeX code" the solution you're looking for because it says "All you have to do is click on 'Build' to compile both your LaTeX and embedded Asymptote code."

Comment: @DJP Thanks, I feel pretty dumb for not seeing that part.

Comment: I wonder if we could run `asymptote` in `RStuio`? thanks!