# Error when using asypictureB package

Tags: asymptote

After seeing this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455544/asymptote-could-not-load-module-filename-1-asy), i tried to draw a bond withe 2 colors using the cylinder connectors like this image:

[image]

So I used the given code but i get error (i used Texstudio and Texmaker).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=crystal}
size(300);
import solids;

currentprojection=orthographic (
camera=(8,5,4),
up=(0,0,1),
target=(2,2,2),
zoom=0.5
);

// save predefined 2D orientation vectors
pair NN=N;
pair SS=S;
pair EE=E;
pair WW=W;

triple C1 = (-3.19898,0.68575,-0.09137);
triple N1 = (-2.00788,-0.15303,-0.05472);
triple H1 = (-3.17155,1.39571,-0.92422);
triple H2 = (-3.31563,1.23754,0.84706);
triple H3 = (-4.08519,0.05549,-0.21396);
triple C2 = (-0.78815,0.67831,0.01256);
triple H4 = (-1.95362,-0.69266,-0.92177);
triple C3 = (0.47237,-0.18670,0.21998);
triple H5 = (-0.86520,1.39211,0.84227);
triple H6 = (-0.69535,1.26040,-0.91400);
triple C4 = (1.73163,0.67172,0.09304);
triple N2 = (0.51467,-1.32801,-0.73516);
triple H7 = (0.46502,-0.59296,1.23918);
triple H8 = (1.39360,-1.82407,-0.57104);
triple H9 = (-0.23067,-1.96899,-0.46111);
triple O1 = (1.80456,1.88884,0.13111);
triple O2 = (2.86188,-0.07112,0.00360);
triple H10 = (3.57354,0.59879,-0.06651);

triple[] Carbon={  
  C1,C2,C3,C4
};
triple[] Nitrogen={
  N1,N2
};
triple[] Oxygen={
  O1,O2
};
triple[] Hydrogen={
  H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9,H10
};

//%place non-atom cube corners



real cylR=0.15;

void Draw(guide3 g,pen p=currentpen){
  draw(
    cylinder(
      point(g,0),cylR,arclength(g),point(g,1)-point(g,0)
    ).surface(
               new pen(int i, real j){
                 return p;
               }
             )
  );
}
void DrawTwoColors(guide3 g,pen p=currentpen,pen q=currentpen){
  draw(
    cylinder(
      point(g,0),cylR,arclength(g)/2,point(g,1)-point(g,0)
    ).surface(
               new pen(int i, real j){
                 return p;
               }
             )
  );
  draw(
    cylinder(
      point(g,1),cylR,arclength(g)/2,point(g,0)-point(g,1)
    ).surface(
               new pen(int i, real j){
                 return q;
               }
             )
  );
}


pen connectPen=lightgray;
pen connectPenH=lightgray;
pen connectPenN=lightblue;
pen connectPenO=red;
pen connectPenC=darkgray;
//Draw(C1--N1,connectPen);
DrawTwoColors(C1--N1,connectPenC,connectPenN);
Draw(N1--C2,connectPen);
Draw(C2--C3,connectPen);
Draw(C3--C4,connectPen);
//Draw(C4--O1,connectPen);
DrawTwoColors(C4--O1,connectPenC,connectPenO);
Draw(H1--C1,connectPen);
Draw(H2--C1,connectPen);
Draw(H3--C1,connectPen);
Draw(H4--N1,connectPen);
Draw(C2--H5,connectPen);
Draw(C2--H6,connectPen);
Draw(C3--H7,connectPen);
Draw(C3--N2,connectPen);
Draw(N2--H8,connectPen);
Draw(N2--H9,connectPen);
//Draw(C4--O2,connectPen);
DrawTwoColors(C4--O2,connectPenC,connectPenO);
Draw(O2--H10,connectPen);

void drawSpheres(triple[] C, real R, pen p=currentpen){
  for(int i=0;i<C.length;++i){
    draw(sphere(C[i],R).surface(
                        new pen(int i, real j){return p;}
                        )
    );
  }
}

real radC=0.45;
real radN=0.6;
real radO=0.6;
real radH=0.3;


drawSpheres(Carbon,radC,darkgray);
drawSpheres(Nitrogen,radN,lightblue);
drawSpheres(Oxygen,radO,red);
drawSpheres(Hydrogen,radH,lightgray);

\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

@quark67 I still have the same errors.

This is screenshoots of all my steps:

1- When i choose Build & View, i get:

[image]

2- When i choose Tools ▶︎ User ▶︎ 1:Asypicture:

[image]

I get this errors :

[image]

@quark67 yes i am on windows 10 and this is my sitting page:

[image]

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `cell-crystal' not found.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{asypicture}

! I can't write on file `cell-compile_asy.bat'.<to be read again>\endgroup \set@typeset@protect \end{document}

Comment: I will write a step by step answer. In short, you need activate `shell-escape`. Note that TexStudio is not my main tool, so perheps there is a better method.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598818/how-can-i-enable-shell-escape, for enabling shell-escape, both TexStudio and TexMaker are covered in that question.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what exactly does Tools > User > Asypicture ? What contain this user command in the settings? Perhaps there is a typo in the command (also perhaps are you on Windows? Sadly, I don't know Windows). Perhaps on Windows you should add .exe or .bat? Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117287/setup-asymptote-in-texmaker, at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99476/132405, at https://texstudio-org.github.io/configuration.html. I hope a Windows user can be more helpful than me.

Comment: @quark67 how can i draw a bond withe 2 colors using Asymptote.

Comment: It's like `[--shell-escape]` doesn't work on Windows (see the orange warning in the message box). I don't know more (not a Windows user). Add the `windows` and `texstudio` tags (and also perhaps in the title of the question, so it can attract more attention).

Comment: Ok @quark67 and thank you very much  for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

In TeXstudio, create the file with the code and name it for example `test-crystal.tex`.

Go to the TeXstudio settings, and choose Buid. Then click on the **+ Add** button:

[image]

You will see:
[image]

In (1) write for example: Asypicture

In (2), write: `txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]`.

Then click on the button **OK** (at bottom right of the setting window in the Mac version) to validate the change.

Then choose Tools ▶︎ User ▶︎ 1:Asypicture.

[image]

Wait few seconds, then you will see:
[image]

And a bunch of files in the directory of the `test-crystal.tex` file. In these files, the .pdf file (yes there is also a file named `test-crystal-crystal_errors.txt` but here it is blank):
[image]

And it contain what you expect:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much quark67 and Marijn for your efforts, I did exactly as you (quark67) told me but I get the following errors: Package asypictureB Error: File `cell-crystal' not found. \end{asypicture}

Comment: @moumou85 I have this message when I click directly on the Build button, but not when I go to Tools > User > Asymptote chain. Can you edit your question with screenshoots of all yours steps please?