Why doesn't Asymptote run?
I try to run a Minimal NOT-Working Example (which is stored in TestAsyPicFile.tex):
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}

\begin{asypicture}{name=test}
triple A = (0,0,0);
\end{asypicture}
    
\end{document}

Looks nice and there should be no problems. However the output is
File `TestAsyPicFile-test' not found. \end{asypicture}

I checked, it does runs PDF chain:

Here are the commands:

-shell-escape is there as recommended by Charles Staats in his asymptoteB.pdf documentation.
Why doesn't is work and what to do for it to work?
LOG file:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4)
(preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)  \write18 enabled.

entering extended mode (TestAsyPicFile.tex

LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2 L3 programming layer <2024-08-30>
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls

Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ucs\utf8x.def


Package ucs Info: utf8x disabled, assuming standard utf8 processing
(ucs)             load ucs package to force utf8x processing.

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\utf8.def

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\omsenc.dfu
)

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ot1enc.dfu
)

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\t1enc.dfu
)

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.dfu
) )))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/asypictureb\asypictureB
.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.c
fg)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
)))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.s
ty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
.code.tex
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
libraryfiltered.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifplatform\ifplatform.s
ty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds
.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.s
ty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty))

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/catchfile\catchfile.s
ty

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty
)))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
tex.def) (TestAsyPicFile.aux)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mk
ii [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] )
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-b
ase.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.c
fg))
        1 file(s) copied.  Attempting to run asy on TestAsyPicFile-test.asy


! Package asypictureB Error:  Possible Asymptote error: warning:
package 'asymptote' is not installed 
         run 'miktex packages install --package-id asymptote' to install it

See the asypictureB package documentation for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    

                                                   l.10     \end{asypicture}
[1 {C:/Users/Serge/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map }]
(TestAsyPicFile.aux) ) (see the transcript file for additional
information) <C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Lo
cal\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600\ecrm1000.pk>

Output written on TestAsyPicFile.pdf (1 page, 1604 bytes). SyncTeX
written on TestAsyPicFile.synctex.gz. Transcript written on
TestAsyPicFile.log.

Process exited with error(s)

I see it says
package 'asymptote' is not installed 
         run 'miktex packages install --package-id asymptote' to install it

but it is installed:

I did install and reinstall it several times (and have no idea how it can be 'not installed')
You might say that asypictureB package has not been updated since 2014. However, it is a lifesaver and as far as I know asymptote itself has not incorporated the error tracking; it also recompiles the pictures. I have ≈300 pictures in the document and to recompile them all takes forever => asypictureB comes handy.

-- Pictures for the comments below:

-- The example from the link below compiles fine:
Process started: pdflatex.exe -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "TestAsyPicFile".tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 \write18 enabled.

entering extended mode
(TestAsyPicFile.tex

LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-08-30>

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.c
ls

Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex
)
)
)
)

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.c
fg
)
 (C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls

Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo)))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/asypictureb\asypictureB
.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.c
fg)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
)))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.s
ty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
.code.tex
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
libraryfiltered.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifplatform\ifplatform.s
ty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds
.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.s
ty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty))

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/catchfile\catchfile.s
ty

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
))))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
tex.def)
No file TestAsyPicFile.aux.

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mk
ii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-b
ase.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.c
fg))


[1
 <./TestAsyPicFile-crystal-eps-converted-to.pdf
>
]
 (TestAsyPicFile.aux)
 )
Output written on TestAsyPicFile.pdf (1 page, 53632 bytes).
SyncTeX written on TestAsyPicFile.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on TestAsyPicFile.log.

Process exited normally



Process started: pdflatex.exe -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "TestAsyPicFile".tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 \write18 enabled.

entering extended mode
(TestAsyPicFile.tex

LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-08-30>

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.c
ls

Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex))
)

)

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.c
fg
)
 (C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls

Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
)
)
)

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/asypictureb\asypictureB
.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.c
fg)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
)))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.s
ty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
.code.tex
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
libraryfiltered.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifplatform\ifplatform.s
ty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds
.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.s
ty)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty))

(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/catchfile\catchfile.s
ty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
))))
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
tex.def) (TestAsyPicFile.aux)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mk
ii

[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-b
ase.sty
(C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.c
fg))

[1 <./TestAsyPicFile-crystal-eps-converted-to.pdf>] (TestAsyPicFile.aux)
 )
Output written on TestAsyPicFile.pdf (1 page, 53632 bytes).
SyncTeX written on TestAsyPicFile.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on TestAsyPicFile.log.

Process exited normally


unrelated but as the log file you show already warns you should not use \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

what happens if you run it by hand asy TestAsyPicFile-test.asy in the document folder

@DavidCarlisle, I wish I know how to do it. I can run the terminal in Windows 10 but after that I strongly rely on TexStudio. My best effort is in the picture that I added to the post itself above. In short - nothing happens; the most likely: I don't know how to use the command line unless it is TexStudio

Does it work if you actually draw something? For example the code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678681/36296 seems to compile fine

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
Runs perfectly on the second go. The picture is generated after the first run, but there is the error message (see the picture above)

Please show the full error message, not the cropped down message texstudio shows you.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I take it back. The example from your link compiles perfectly. (deleted it, used the non-working code above, obtained the error, cleaned the auxiliary files, inserted the code from the link, works fine on the first go) — posted the Log of this (good) compilation as the addon to the post

I know that the other comments are from people of some authority, but I would humbly recommend TeXLive over MiKTeX if your intention is to run asymptote. MiKTeX uses an outdated ghostscript with some path naming conflicts - at least when I download it.
